# How to check if the customLogs are getting uploaded to Azure Application Insights

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I am trying to add custom events to Azure Application Insights by providing the instrumentation key as follows:

```
    public void WriteAgentLogs(string message, int AgentId, int ScheduleId)
    {
        TelemetryClient _telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration() { InstrumentationKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" });
        _telemetryClient.InstrumentationKey = ""xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"";
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        parameters.Add("Message", message);
        parameters.Add("AgentId", AgentId.ToString());
        parameters.Add("ScheduleId", ScheduleId.ToString());
        parameters.Add("ScheduleStartDate", DateTime.Now.ToString());

        // check and add metrics here
        var metrics = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        if (duration != null)
        {
            metrics.Add("Duration", (double)duration);
        }

        _telemetryClient.TrackEvent("Agents", parameters, metrics);

        _telemetryClient.TrackTrace("Agents");

        _telemetryClient.TrackTrace(message, SeverityLevel.Information);
    }
```

After the code got executed, I am getting the following in the output window:

```
The program '[9672] LoadDataToAppInsights.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[9672] LoadDataToAppInsights.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

When I go back to the Azure portal and check for these logs, the logs are not getting uploaded. I am unable to figure out where the issue is arising. How can I rectify this issue?

Comment: what's the kind of the project? console project or web project?

Comment: @IvanYang console application

Comment: update: add sample code

Answer (score 1):

Updated:
first, you need to install Microsoft.ApplicationInsights(here I install the latest version 2.7.2) via nuget:
[image]

Then, include the following namespace:

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
```

For a console project, you need add the following code after the Trackxx() method:

```
    System.threading.thread.sleep(5000);
    _telemetryClient.Flush();
```

Here is my sample code:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "your key";
            var telemetry = new TelemetryClient();

            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            parameters.Add("Message", "message test");
            parameters.Add("AgentId", "Agent test");
            parameters.Add("ScheduleId", "schedule test");
            parameters.Add("ScheduleStartDate", DateTime.Now.ToString());

            var metrics = new Dictionary<string, double>();

                metrics.Add("Duration", 999.99);

            telemetry.TrackEvent("Agents event", parameters, metrics);

            telemetry.TrackTrace("Agents trace");

            telemetry.TrackTrace("message trace", SeverityLevel.Information);
            //telemetry.TrackTrace("0919 after today...");

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            telemetry.Flush();

            Console.WriteLine("done now.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

After executed, if the following message appears in the output window, means upload successfully:
[image]

Then go to azure portal -> your application insights -> Overview blade -> click search, you should see the logs you uploaded(if may take a few minutes to be shown on portal):
[image]

Click on an log to see details:
[image]

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: which namespace are you using for TelemetryConfiguration? i am using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights but getting error that TelemetryConfiguration does not exist in the context

Comment: @Harry, first, install Microsoft.ApplicationInsights(version 2.7.2) via nuget. For using TelemetryConfiguration, please include the following "using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;" . I also updated my answer for this.

Comment: Sorry for the late response! The Flush() solved the issue

Comment: happy that you solved it. could you please help mark it as an answer? It would be useful for others. thanks:)

Comment: I don't have enough reputations for my vote to be visible